# Saving edited articles in backend redirects me to the homepage in front-end without saving the changes

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, administrator

I have a joomla 3.0 website that is stressing me out. The issue is that I can not edit/update articles on the website.

When I login to the administrator panel and select an article to edit then make changes and try to save it, Joomla redirects me to the homepage in the front-end and the article changes are not being saved.

What could be the source of the issue?

Comment: try to disable 3rd party plugins and also make sure you are using the default ISIS template for backend.

Comment: I think I know your question/problem from Stackoverflow. So, I updated your question to reflect your actual problem. The way you wrote it was completely unclear and it was hard for others to understand your problem. If I didn't explain your problem well, then consider to revise it at your own.

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently move your website from a host to another? If your hosting provider uses CPanel, you might have [ModSecurity](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Apache+Module:+ModSecurity) enabled.

Go to your CPanel->Security->ModSecurity and disable it.